# Caching frontpage in cloudflare free?

Tags: caching, cookies, cdn

I've set up cloudflare caching of Drupal's frontpage by adding a Page Rule for my Drupal base URL, with a "Cache Everyting" setting (otherwise, caching is enabled only for certain file extensions). I've installed the Cloudflare module, and enabling `$conf['reverse_proxy']`.

However, it seems that after authenticating, users see the anonymous homepage. If I go to /drupal/user, I see the user's page (so I know login works). I don't understand how this happens, since the Drupal anonymous pages are supposed to set 'Vary: Cookie' (which Cloudflare supposedly obeys), and authenticated users should send a session cookie.

Is anyone using cloudflare successfully for dynamic content? What settings would help? Any ideas?

**NOTE**. I haven't set conf['omit_vary_cookie']. Debugging with curl -I shows the appropriate `Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding`. Under Firefox, after authenticating, a request to `/drupal/` sends a session cookie.

Comment: *"Drupal anonymous pages are supposed to set 'Vary: Cookie'"* - so is it happening on your site? You can test it, we can't.

Comment: I haven't set `conf['omit_vary_cookie']`. `curl -I` shows `Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding`. In Firefox, after authentication, a request to `/drupal/` contains a session cookie, but the response from drupal/cloudflare only has `Vary: Accept-Encoding` (as well as `X-Drupal-Cache:Hit` and `CF-Cache-Status:Hit`)

Comment: If cookie is supposed to be set, or header to be sent, but is not, then it is a bug in core or module, and should be resolved in module's issue queue. If header is sent and cookie set, but browser or caching server ignores it - then it's their bug. Hard to tell now.

Comment: Even without cloudflare, the response from /drupal/ to an authenticated request contains only `Vary:Accept-Encoding`, not `Vary:Cookie` (but in that case it also contains the proper authenticated page, as well as `Cache-Control:no-cache etc`). I think that's the way Drupal does things. But Cloudflare shouldn't normally send a cached page if the request has a session cookie...

Comment: ... I'm a little surprised I don't find more articles on the web on Drupal + Cloudflare... Avoiding a server hit for the anonymous frontpage (and the individual nodes) should be a common use-case.

Comment: Sadly, if your server fails to send vary:cookie header, then it is a bug. Bug where? Hard to tell. Either Drupal does not even try to set it, or Drupal tries, but webserver prevents it. Can you consult it with your sysadmin?

Comment: I am the sysadmin. But for a `Cache-control:no-cache` page, no `Vary:Cookie` needs to be set, as the page should not be cached in the first place. I've just tried with drupal 7 on localhost: as soon as Drupal sees a session cookie, it stops sending `Vary:Cookie`, and start sending `Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"`

Comment: Exactly the same problem. If an authenticated user visits a page previously visited by an anonymous user, s/he suddenly sees the cached version of that page. The fact that the authenticated user has a session cookie is simply ignored.

https://github.com/d8-contrib-modules/cloudflare/issues/4 solves this by using "Bypass cache cookie" setting, but that feature is only available for the most expensive Cloudflare plan (Enterprise).

I wonder, is there really no elegant answer to this problem for the majority of Drupal users running under Cloudflare?

Comment: Seems like this support article might be relevant here? https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217343117-What-headers-can-I-vary-the-cache-on-